# How do you organize multiple view "levels" with Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am making a single-page app using Backbone.js. Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish: http://jsfiddle.net/Qhtvz/

Basically there would be a the profile view then the inner view, when the profile changes, the inner view would need to reload (with the new info) as well. How would you organize and program views with Backbone.js to allow for this?

Answer (score 0):

in the past i've done this manually, but in my lastest project i am experimenting with the backbone plugin created by Tim Branyen,
his backbone.layoutmanager can handle nested views, you can swap out jquery templates for another templating engine if you want...

here is the link to the github project page
https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager

if you want to do it yourself, i suggest creating a view manager yourself, or your code will be too complicated too fast. just a view manager where you pass in the view you want to be shown and it handles replacing the old view with the new. (calling the proper unbind methods / remove methods)